# Why so many specs for RCD vs US GFCI (or RCDs?)

Tags: rcd

Why are there so many RCD (Residual Current Device) specs and mA tripping thresholds for use in equipments in Europe vs the USA where they were not used (but only 5mA GFCI for personal safety)?

Don't they use any EGC (Equipment Grounding Conductor connected directly to the utility transformer) in Europe that requires such massive RCD specs?

Lastly. Is the RCD in Europe compatible when used in the USA 240v ac (red and black wire)? Has anyone successfully used RCD in the USA? In theory it should work because the toroid only detect imbalances but some people comment that they were not compatible for some reasons. True?

Comment: It is possible to buy 240V GFCI breakers in the US. They take up two slots in the breaker panel and still rely on having a neutral connection. I can't imagine that it would be possible to build a code compliant system using European gear. But I don't think the frequency difference between US and Europe would pose any problem for European RCD devices.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different classes of RCD's and GFCI's.   The 5mA 5 second test is the most common residential for bathroom grounded outlets or wherever secondary earth paths exist. ( see AC-2)

The selection criteria is based on location between source and load, [country laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device#Regulation_and_adoption) , and to avoid nuisance trips yet to prevent:

- equipment failures (AC-4),
- fires  & human injury(AC-3),
- human shock (AC-2)
- higher risks for medical instrument use  (AC-1)

[image]

The typical HIPOT leakage test in America is < 100uA using HVDC to eliminate the AC filter earth current but where 500uA is allowed per unit which comes from the EMI ground noise PI filter current.  Up to 2.5mA earth current is allowed per system that contains many PSU's.

Both RCD's and GFCI's measure the differences  in line current to magnetically activate a relay. The construction depends on the current rating and residual difference threshold and thus the acceleration which affects the response time.  Higher thresholds or time delays are selected to avoid nuisance trips such as from transient voltage suppressor currents to to earth.

Although a 5mA threshold device is more protective than 30 mA device, in residential areas with high humidity and dust, the device may false trip until the moisture or contaminants that cause the internal leakage to earth evaporate or are heated away.

Residential RCD's with 30mA threshold may be common but in [America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device#North_America)  GFCI's now must have a 5mA/25ms threshold on outlets near moist connections to earth. Laundry room, unfinished concrete basement, outdoors, kitchen, bathroom.  Old houses with 2 wire outlets may use these in place or rewiring the house with 3 wire if labelled as "no equip. ground".

Comment: How about higher than 5mA (in USA RCDs)? Why are European RCDs have ratings from 30mA to 500mA. Maybe they don't use any EGC but just local electrode hence need it for protection?

Comment: European designers also like discrimination, so we might use for example a 300mA/300ms unit at the incomer, then a 100mA/100ms part at a sub distribution board and finally a 30mA/30ms part for a final circuit. This ensures that a fault will be cleared as locally as possible leaving the rest of the facility with power.  If we did not discriminate on time then a stiff earth fault could trip all three levels of protection. Plenty of TN-C-S used over here, but you still want discrimination. I would note that only a few of the RCDs are not special order items, 30mA/30ms being the most common.

Comment: How common are RCD receptacles in Europe just like the GFCI receptacles in the US where you put in the wall? Do these RCD receptacles exist?

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Residual-Current-Devices-Ground-Fault-Interrupters/129085/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=rcd

Comment: There is not a single RCD receptacle there Tony. Anyway. Do you believe that RCDs without any electronics are more reliable?

Comment: @Jtl the 1st item was a Receptacle and passive 30mA.   No opinion on reliability

Comment: It's not a receptacle but a plug-in adaptor. I'm referring to permanently installed receptacle.

Comment: 30mA is too high for a single outlet and it seems they did not wish to have this product used in America which is far more (6x) sensitive perhaps due to 1/2 voltage thus for the same R only 1/2 stray leakage current..  EU chose to use central protection which could be a nuisance at 5mA on shared rooms, yet typically false triggers and real triggers come only from high humidity areas like showers and cooking areas near earthed conductors.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Europe, RCDs are usually installed to protect entire circuits, not just single socket outlets.  Each appliance may leak a new mA to ground, even if it is working correctly.  Electronic devices with suppression capacitors, and devices with mineral insulated heating elements (such as cookers and water heaters) are usually the worst for this.  So using a 5mA or 10mA RCD will probably result in nuisance tripping.

So for protecting people from electrocution, 30mA was chosen as a compromise.  The 30mA is the maximum at which the RCD must trip.  Manufacturing variances mean that some will trip at lower currents.

Earthing (grounding) arrangements vary wildly across Europe.  Here in the UK we still use three different arrangements - TT, TN-S and TN-C-S.

If it is a TT installation, the supplier provides no ground, and the customer must use an earth rod, which is **not** connected to the supply neutral.  Even a dead short between live and the consumer's earth will not pass enough current to blow the supply fuse.  So it is common to fit a 100mA time-delayed RCD to the incoming supply, which will trip instead.  In large commercial installations, a 100mA RCD may still nuisance trip.  So it may be necessary to increase the RCD to 300mA or more.  Note that these RCDs are there to detect and clear faults, not to protect people from electrocution.

100mA or more RCDs are sometimes also used where long cable runs are necessary, and the time to clear the fault by a fuse blowing or circuit breaker tripping may be too long.

European 230V RCDs will have four terminals - live in, live out, neutral in and neutral out.  There is no provision for two phases, plus neutral.  So there is no guarantee that an RCD connected only across the two phases would detect a fault current leaking to neutral or ground.

Comment: For TT arrangement. How do you protect your main circuit breaker panel chassis from hot wire to chassis short since there is no ground conductor direct to the transformer?

Comment: @Jtl It's up to the designer, but typically a separate 100mA time delay RCD in a plastic case before the main board and/or a special insulation kit added to the breaker board to prevent the meter tails from touching any metal before the first RCD.

Comment: If the 100mA trip, then the entire house power goes out. Doesn't this happen often?  And why is there a time delay feature?

Comment: @Jtl The time delay feature is to ensure that a downstream 30mA RCD trips first.  That way, only one circuit goes out.  The 100mA one should never trip.

Comment: Although 30mA might not be fatal, it is enough to cause muscles to contract and not let go.

Comment: So the EU specs are inferior. So does that mean they use AC-3 specs for residential?

Comment: @Jtl I would add that 30mA RCDs rarely nuisance trip.  My house is wired to older standards, with all socket outlets in the house, and in the garage, and the electric shower all on one 30mA RCD.  Except when it's been tested, it has never tripped in the last 8 years.

Comment: Without electronics inside the RCD, you can still push the test button? What if it were defective? Haven't you tried using US 5mA GFCI on your appliances? You can get it by this configuration... https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/921/dYivjT.jpg

Comment: @Jtl I have no idea what's inside the RCD.  It worked on the test button when I moved into the house, and electricians working here have tested it since.  Nobody here seems to worry about lower current RCDs.  I believe some parts of Europe do use 10mA in bathrooms.  We just ban socket outlets in bathrooms instead!

Comment: Normally one does not connect more than 3-3pronged appliances with SMPS and ground leakage currents of 0.25mA so even with 3 appliances it won’t false  trip at 5mA so 30mA is for high humidity shower leakage and burning toast in the kitchen in high %RH leakage users who get false trips. that’s why UL approved GFCI’s are better.